# How would one characterize the argument that God could be physically impossible but chance can't be?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

A lot of design arguments, especially ones that deal with fine tuning, seem to imply the notion that something is too improbable to be true, therefore a designer may have caused it.
But no matter how improbable an observation is, we know that P(chance|observation) is non zero. In other words, unless we're talking about things that contradict physical laws, such as say spontaneously transforming into a raven, we can never say that P(chance|observation) is 0.

Even extreme cases such as landing a dice on 6 1,000,000 straight times confers a probability. It can never be the case that P(chance|1,000,000 straight rolls of six) is 0, no matter how much more likely design is. However, it can be the case, especially with God, that the P(God|*some observation*) is 0 simply because He may not exist or if He did, may not have intended to produce that observation.

What would this argument be characterized as?

Comment: There is a difference between "The probability of P is very low so it must be false" and "The probability of P is so low that a rational thinker should assume it is false". It is actually possible according to quantum mechanics for a raven to spontaneously come into being; however, if someone tells you that a particular raven has come into being that way, the rational response is to disbelieve that.

Comment: The rational response is to disbelieve that only because an alternative theory is more likely, such as the person claiming this to be lying. There is no such thing as “the probability of P is so low that a rational thinker should think it is false.” If there is, what is this P?

Comment: I would read Dostoyevsky's masterpiece The Demons and leave it at that. Dostoyevsky's idea was to believe this whether true or not. Truth is the red herring. It's a matter of Will

Comment: @temptrt, no the rational response is to disbelieve that a one in 10^100 possibility occurred to create a raven even if you have no alternative explanation for how the raven got there. Asking for a threshold is a deflection because obviously there is no firm number, but when you get to a 1 in 10^20 or so, you are well past the point where it is rational to believe something happened by chance.

Comment: No matter how low the probability of something is, you must show that an alternative is more likely. So in the case of a 10^100 possibility occurring, you must show that an alternative creating that is at a higher probability. Evidence is fundamentally comparative

Comment: What exactly does the event "chance" refer to here? When you write P(chance), it almost looks like you're talking about the probability that there is a probability, which isn't really anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an argument as you need to define God first.
If you take the conclusions of the arguments used by theists throughout history (even as early as Aristotle), then God would be the uncaused first cause, that which is necessary and from which all contingent entities came (contingency argument), or the purely actual actualiser / unmoved mover (argument from motion or change, see Ed Feser, Aristotle, or Aquinas). In other words, God would be the ultimate cause of all things and the ultimate explanation for how anything exists at all right now.

Therefore, P(God existing | Observation) could be 1 (if God exists, then your ability to observe anything would be dependent on God's existence) or 0 (if God doesn't exist). Unfortunately this doesn't really say anything as we could apply it to many other things.

That being said, it is interesting without knowing to consider P(God existing | Observation). An very rough approximation of an answer could be reached by considering the various arguments for God throughout history such as the argument from change (Ed Feser), the contingency argument, the kalam cosmological argument, the moral argument, etc.

Comment: One can just define the "god" hypothesis as "powerful agent outside the universe, with the ability to create it, chose to create it with the purpose of supporting life within it eventually".  One need not have a more specific or detailed "god" hypothesis to evaluate this fairly open-ended alternative set of hypotheses.

Comment: @Dcleve The question specifically references the fine tuning argument which has historically been used as an argument for a single immaterial creator, the same basic definition of God that I gave. If you don't define God then you don't have an argument.

Comment: Andrew -- one of the points made by the Intelligent Design movement is that intentionality does not need to presuppose a specific set of features to evaluate evidence for or against intentionality.  SETI does not presuppose much at all about the agents it searches for.  And an Omni-God is far more readily tested by tests like the Problem of Evil than by Fine Tuning.

Comment: "SETI does not presuppose much at all about the agents it searches for." I'm glad to hear it. But now I'm worried they won't be able to recognize what they are searching for. They must have some idea what would count as evidence for non-human people, surely?

Comment: "*Praise God from whom all blessings flow...*"

Comment: Possibly. But do we know that extra-terrestrial life is a blessing? It might be evil. It might be a mixture of good and bad.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing a lot of very similar questions from you, with the common purpose of trying out mostly weak rationalizations to dismiss any God hypothesis. This one fits into that category.

The epistemology of methodological naturalism relies upon probability evaluations.  And the probability that a single universe, which came spontaneously into existence with ANY constants of the Standard Model hat could support life in that universe, per our best understanding of Quantum Mechanics, is astonishingly small.

What this does is undercut some of the bad rationalizations that atheists have used to justify their faith-views.

This is because, to come up with a naturalist explanation for Fine Tuning, a physicalist must admit that either:

1. Our universe is not causally closed, and other things act upon it (and causal closure is THE key assumption of physicalism), or
2. We do not understand our physics well enough to explain Fine Tuning, and future discoveries need to be made in fundamental aspects of physics

or both.

But 1), physicalism, is the key argument that atheists make against God hypotheses being plausible.  And 2), that we know our physics well enough to dismiss the possibility of either a spirit world, or spirt-matter interaction, is the key argument that atheists make against interactive spiritual dualism.  And the combo of the two, that God hypotheses are unnecessary, is likewise repeatedly claimed by atheists.

What Fine Tuning shows, is that "agency" hypotheses cannot be legitimately dismissed by atheists, they instead have to actually do the work to show their views are more plausible than agency views.

The best thinking I have seen from atheists on Fine Tuning is to DO that sort of comparative argument.  This sort of argument was spelled out by Leonard Susskind in the first several pages of The Cosmic Landscape. What he argued was that, yes, our universe is surprisingly adapted to support life, but it is not OPTIMIZED for life, and design/agency hypotheses would lead to an expectation of a universe ACTUALLY tuned for life. But life could only appear in our universe after several billion years, and only inhabit a vanishly small fraction of our universe (some tiny fraction of 1% of its mass and energy), and is continually at risk of extermination from larger events/forces in the areas life inhabits (Novas, comet impacts, etc).  Our universe is BARELY capable of supporting life, it is not TUNED to support life!  What Suskind then proposed is that the existence of a multiverse would predict exactly this sort of "apparent fine tuning" in which the anthropic principle would predict that almost all emergent life would discover they lived in a surprisingly "tuned" but not actually optimized universe for life. This explains apparent fine tuning, but now introduces a lot of unsupported and suspect hypotheses (the infinite multiverse, etc).

The counter from an agency perspective, is that a creator agent could end up producing non-optimization, but to do so, would end up with a much more complex creator hypothesis than simple monotheism suggests.  An incompetent creator, or one of only limited knowledge and power, or a botched creation, or creation by a squabbling committee -- could lead to non-optimize universe that could still support life.  Are these more or less plausible than a multiverse?  I don't think we have the ability to evaluate that.  Both sets of explanations have a LOT of unsupported assumptions.

Meanwhile, the issues within physicalism -- that reductionism is not  working, that physics does not understand 95% of our universe (dark energy and dark matter), and causal closure is an only useful assumption in science, but cannot be shown to be true either in physics, and is refuted by pluralism and emergence, and instead appears not compatible even with consciousness -- leaves an atheist case as having to be much less than absolute.

Atheism can be argued as being a workable/plausible hypothesis that has not been refuted, and a plausibly better hypothesis than theism, but the "presumption of atheism" and the dismissal of theistic thinking by many atheist apologists, both which characterize a lot of current atheist apologism, are bad arguments.

Comment: Who said that a single universe spontaneously came into existence? Secondly, what does it even mean to talk about probability here? How do you evaluate the probability of those parameters being fine tuned? The main advantage atheists have over theists is that theists often assert things. They'll assert that there is an omnipotent god who's eternal and necessary. Why can't one then simply assert that those fine tuned parameters were necessary?

Comment: Answers: a) There is only one observed universe, and it had an origin in time.  This is what cosmologists say.  b) The potential range of the Standard Model constants can be reasonably estimated by the values of the other constants.  The minimal possible range of the CC can be established by its variance over the course of the BB model.  c) a claim of "logical necessity" can be evaluated logically, and almost all such claims are readily rejected as false.  Calling contingent constants "necessary" is a blatant lie driven by motivated propaganda desires -- IE "religious" apologism.

Comment: The Universe was designed by a committee. This actually explains a lot! Best hypothesis I have heard about it. Even in the Bible God refers to self as a plural: the Elohim.

Answer (score 0):

*Chance*, the belief is, *excludes* (a) *cause(s)* and god has been defined as *the first cause*, the *primum movens* (the first mover). If an event is a chance occurrence, god (the *first cause*) is no longer part of the equation so to speak - to say *god created the universe* IF the universe came to be by fluke is to be *not even wrong*.

However, such a belief seems to be wrong for the simple reason that chance *doesn't actually exclude* (a) cause(s). Chance appears to only *randomly select* among causes. Imagine a sample space of causes A, B, C, D; all chance does is choose one of these causes randomly and it so happens that it chose the right cause (say C) that would go on to create our universe. It could've been A or B or D in which case a different universe would've been born or absolutely nothing would've happened.

Then there's the matter of *intention*; chance affairs are *unintended* i.e. there's no *agency* behind them, they're *unplanned* and if the universe's existence was a chance happening, god - an agency who reportedly *intended* to create the universe - is not part of the picture. Of course it's possible that God *accidentally* created the universe (that would explain a lot but that's a topic for another discussion).

Me two *sikkas*

Answer (score 0):

According to our current knowledge of the laws of physics God is an impossible thing.

First, we have no observation of any god, no knowledge about the process by which gods usually evolve. We cannot assign any probability value for the existence of God.

Second, we are not aware of any such law of physics that could allow an entity to evolve with the capability to alter the laws of physics.

Chance, on the other hand, is just normal everyday business as usual.